# Group by count by a subgroup in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have example code here

```
df |>
  dplyr::group_by(label) |>
  dplyr::summarize(avg_col = mean(count_col, na.rm = TRUE),
                   med_col = median(count_col, na.rm  = TRUE),
                   n = n()) |>
  dplyr::arrange(desc(avg_col))
```

I want to get the percentage of times count_col is 1.
How can i do this in the summarize statement?
I first need to filter to count_col ==1 than divide it by the total count.

I'm nto sure how to do this thoough.

Comment: `prct = sum(count_col == 1) / n() * 100`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mean` on a logical vector to get the percentage (* 100)

```
df |>
  dplyr::group_by(label) |>
  dplyr::summarize(perc_count_one = 100 * mean(count_col == 1, na.rm TRUE), 
                   avg_col = mean(count_col, na.rm = TRUE),
                   med_col = median(count_col, na.rm  = TRUE),
                   n = n()) |>
  dplyr::arrange(desc(avg_col))
```